# Is it ok for Repository Pattern to contain unusual method names?

Tags: design-patterns, repository-pattern

For example I need to find a user which its `status` is 0 and its name is `John`. So beside usual methods for a Repository pattern (e.g. `find`, `create`), I decide to create a method in `UsersRepository` called `findJohnWithStatusZero` or to be more generic, a method called `findUserWithStatusAndName`

UsersRepository.php

```
<?php

class UsersRepository
{
    public function create(array $data)
    {
        //
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function findUserWithStatusAndName($status, $name)
    {
        return User::where('status', $status) -> where('name', $name) -> first();
    }

}
```

Controller.php:

```
...
public function index(UsersRepository $users)
{
    $john_zero = $users -> findUserWithStatusAndName(0, 'john');
}
...
```

I want to know, if I use these customized methods in my Repository, do I violate the Repository Pattern principles?

Edit: I provided more generic method name instead of `findJohnWithStatusZero`

Comment: Not necessarily, based on [my reasoning here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180501/what-specific-issue-does-the-repository-pattern-solve/13189143#13189143). But "findJohnWithStatusZero" sounds oddly specific for a repository method. If it were "GetPremierCustomers" or something like that it would make more sense.

Comment: @EricKing I know `findJohnWithStatusZero` is a bit strange. It is an example. The more realistic names could be `findByType`, `findByRegisterDate`, `deleteOldPosts`

Comment: What is your idea if I use findByType, findByRegisterDate, deleteOldPosts method names?

Comment: The examples you are providing are more like Service Layer or Business Layer methods, not repository methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the repository level I would recommend having a more generic method like `Find(User user)` or `findUserByNameAndStatus(name, status)`. Getting overly specific like your example is unlikely to be a useful method for re-usability, and it's probably embedding business logic into your repository that is better implemented elsewhere. Specific methods aren't bad in a repository, but you should be able to answer why `findJohnWithStatusZero` is a method, but not `findSaraWithStatusTwo`, will you eventually need `findBillWithStatusOne`? It should generally be obvious why a method in your repository exists.

Comment: Thanks. I meant something like `findUserByNameAndStatus`. So you say it is ok to use method names like `findUserByNameAndStatus`?

Comment: @AliN11 having multiple `findByThing` methods is almost expected, its just a balancing act of how many is too many. separate find by name, status and name/status would be too many overlapping methods, but findById and FindByName are probably separate enough.

Answer (score 2):

This is typically solved using a `search()` function.

```php
public function search($searchModel)
{
    return User::where('status', $searchModel->status) -> where('name', $searchModel->name) -> first();
}

class SearchModel { 
    public $status = 0; 
    public $name = NULL;
}
```